# effect of static files in django not seen immediately

Tags: django, static

I am using django 2.0.7. My folder structure is like
The project folder is mysite and inside that I have a app installed polls. Inside polls I have all the all the usual files. I have a templates and static folder and inside both of these there is a polls folder. Inside the polls folder again I am storing my static and template files.So the overall structure is like this-

```
mysite
    polls
        template
            polls
                index.html

        static
            polls
                style.css
```

Now I want to use css file for index.html. so I added this line in index.html.

```
{% load static %}
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
```

Now whatever I am doing in css file that is showing in the browser but the problem is its not instantaneous. I mean right now if I change the color of a para to yellow and then reload the page then I cannot see the effect immediately. I have to wait for some time.
I also included this in the settings file

```
STATIC_URL='/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because django is saving your css file in Chache storage and once file loaded, next time it loads from chache, so you didn't changes. Try to use Incognito window and form clearing chache and more info about django chache refer to - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/

Use Dummy Caching (for development) - this doesn't actually cache so you could have it on your development side.

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
}
}
```

Comment: I tried opening in the incognito window but nothing happened